# Unity Make sprite visible only to shaders

Tags: unity, gui, blending

I have made a shader for my UI buttons, the sprites should be black and white, so they can be used as a mask when blending. They should allow for the image behind them to pass through the whiter pixels and be blocked by the darker ones.

I want to use this effect for my menu, have a black background and a colored one (like a gradient or a pattern), let the colored one pass only through the buttons and the black one everywhere else.

My shader does just that, but with one problem. I can't hide the colored background from the camera. If I change it's layer it is useless (I guess because it is the child of a canvas), and if I use a regular sprite (non UI) it is just ignored by the camera and the buttons don't pick up the color.

How can I achieve this effect, having the sprite be invisible to the camera but visible to the shaders of the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Although it may not be what you are looking for, I generated this to show how to use the stencil buffer to achieve what you want:

[image: UI stenciling]

The "black-shader" could just `return (0,0,0,1);` but could also sample from a texture (animated gradient, etc.)

Comment: I cannot check any of that rightaway, I will share my results as soon as I al able to try that.

Comment: @user3195897, I have yet to open Unity and would love to know how you actually implement this in it. (i.e. replace the GL references)

Comment: OK I'm totally new to shaders, I just copied the sprites-default shader and played with the blend value,  so according to what I just read this method would be used instead of blending, am I right

Comment: I recommended using the stencil-*buffer* since you are doing 2D, but you could also do this with a stencil-*texture*, in 2D or 3D. You could also have buttons (only) output a second color to a second rendertarget and sample that texture later to choose between "black" and "button"; if the sampled color is 0, it's not button. There are many ways to do it, but I think the stencil will be the easiest.

Comment: You can still use alpha-blending for the color buffer, even while filling the stencil. The actual stenciling is done during the final pass where you just render a full-screen quad, twice. One of the final-pass shaders will output (0,0,0,1) and the other will output the color sampled from the same location as the current pixel. The stencil setup just selects between "fill the 0's" and "fill the not-0's".

Comment: Well it seems a little hard, but let me see: apparently I can't use an arbitrary size for my texture (gradient) and simply have it to be stretched to fill the screen. And apparently the results will not be antialiassed since there is only 1 and 0. I think I get what I need for the "parameters" but what about all that complicated code inside pass, unity documentation doesn't seem too useful in this particular topici

Comment: @user3195897, I didn't even know what "inside pass" meant until now. I've finally opened Unity and have found both where to set this up, and also a [good link with sample code](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html)! I will follow you to chat if you'd like to work on this together; especially if you can send me what you have as a starting point since I don't even know how to create or place stuff in the scene yet :)

Comment: Well that sounds good to me